# Error while proxying request kubectl proxy

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm trying to follow this documentation https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/.

After running this command

```
kubectl proxy --port=8080 &
```

I get the output

```
Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:8080
```

However when I run "curl http://localhost:8080/api/" to hit the server, I get this response

```
dial tcp: lookup localhost: no such host
```

Any idea's why I would get this response?

EDIT:
I'm using a VPN to connect to corporate network. When I disable the VPN I still get the same message for both localhost and 127.0.0.1 (same exact message for both).

I'm not using `kubeadm`.

When I run `host localhost` I get this output

```
localhost has address 127.0.0.1
localhost has IPv6 address ::1
```

`cat /etc/hosts`

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
# Added by Docker Desktop
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

Comment: Do you have localhost entry in your `/etc/hosts`?
What happen if you try curling `127.0.0.1` instead?

Comment: I have 127.0.0.1       localhost, 255.255.255.255 broadcasthost, ::1             localhost, and 127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal in my `/etc/hosts`. Same thing happens when I curl 127.0.0.1

Comment: I am not able to replicate your issue. Can you tell more about your environment? Its local or corporate machine, are you using kubeadm, what version is kubernetes version? Are you using any VPN? What does host localhost say when run on your system ? So when you curl 127.0.0.1 you get exactly the same error message? Could you share your `cat /etc/hosts` output in the question?

Comment: @PjoterS I added some more information to the comments. I'm using my work computer and connected to the corporate network via VPN. I disabled VPN and still got the same output `dial tcp: lookup localhost: no such host` for both localhost and `127.0.0.1`

Comment: It seems it's your machine issue. What OS are you using, could you provide `kubectl config`? Output of `netstat -nr` while you are using VPN and when you turn it of, host localhost, `curl -v 127.0.0.1:8080`. What about default `kubectl proxy` on port `8001`?
Please hide all private, confidential and sensitive data (like public IPs or credentials).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you might have http_proxy set on you system , so try curl with noproxy as following :

`curl --noproxy '*' http://localhost:8080`

If you want to check if the http_proxy is set :

`echo $http_proxy`